# How to get specific nested child component from parent component slot in render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-render-function

I am conditionally rendering a child component using render function. Here is an example of the parent component with the child component:

```xml
<Parent :index="1">
  <Child> ... </Child>
  <Child> ... </Child>
  <Child> ... </Child>
</Parent>
```

in the render function of `Parent` component, I have the following code to conditionally render the child component like this:

```js
return () => {
  const content = slots.default?.();
  const children = content?.filter(child => child.type === Child);
  const childToRender = children?.[props.index] ?? h('div')
  return h('div', {}, () => [childToRender]);
}
```

the code is working as expected.

However, I would like to wrap one of the child component with another component. For example like this:

```xml
<Parent :index="1">
  <Child> ... </Child>
  <ChildWrapper> ... </ChildWrapper>
  <Child > ... </Child>
</Parent>
```

where `ChildWrapper.vue` looks like this:

```xml
<template>
  <Child> <slot/> </Child>
</template>
```

which evidently the filter function (`content?.filter(child => child.type === Child)`) will not pick up the `Child` component in the `ChildWrapper` component.

If I inspect the ChildWrapper VNode's children property, it shows an object (with the default slot function) instead of an array with `Child` component which I expected. So my question is how do I get hold of the nested `Child` component?

### Background of problem

Say the parent component is a `Tab` or a `Carousel` component and the child component is a `TabItem` or `CarouselItem` component. The reason I made a `ChildWrapper` component is to extend/override some of the props in the default `Child` component. The parent and child components are from a component library, and it has no knowledge of what `ChildWrapper` is, so the parent component can't control how `ChildWrapper` should render.

Comment: "how do I get hold of the nested Child component?" - by calling default slot function.

Comment: calling the default slot function will return the content of the component's slot not the content in the component itself

Comment: seems XY problem, i've never seen a problem like that, seems should be solved another easier way. othewise you should setup and render ChildWrapper yourself and check its children which is overkill and not optimal for performance to render conditional components just to check their children

Comment: You can add <Child> yourself around the content, as long as Parent is supposed to be aware of ChildWrapper and the way it works. You can't do this directly the way you do, you need to render ChildWrapper in order to get its content. As said, this looks like XY problem, consider reasking the question with an explanation of your specific case

Comment: added the background of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that obtaining specific, deeply nested child components directly from the parent is not a recommended approach. Child components may be nested deeply, beyond just one level.

Using `provide` and `inject` allows you to achieve your goal seamlessly, in my opinion.

I will provide a simple example to illustrate this.

Parent component:

```
import { provide, ref } from 'vue'

const id = -1;
const current = ref(0)

function getId() {
  id++;
  return id;
}

provide('provide-key', {
  getId,
  current
})
```

Child component:

```
import { inject,computed } from 'vue'

const { getId, current } = inject('provide-key');
const id = getId();
const isShow = computed(() => id === current.value);
```

The provided code is not complete, but I believe the main idea is conveyed.

Comment: thanks i have followed your direction and its working

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches.

1. Make a state (whichever state manager your using) like:

```js
exports defineState({
  visibleChildType: 'type'
})
```

In the Parent component, use whatever logic is required set the state value.

Then, move the conditional render condition out of the Parent and into the child itself, while importing the state: like,

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <div v-if="type === visibleChildType" />
</template>

<script>
import visibleChildType from 'parentState'
</script>
```

2. Move the wrapper into the Child component itself.

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <ChildWrapper v-if="needsWrapper">
    <div />
  </ChildWrapper>

  <div v-else=" />
</template>
```

This way, the child can wrap itself when necessary and your parents component doesn't need to be refactored.